# Export SQL DB to a BACPAC using Export Data-Tier Application - Check Status

Tags: export, ssms, status, sql-server-2017, bacpac

I am trying to export data around 30 GB from SQL server table in bacpac format ,using Export Data-Tier Application in SSMS 2017 version .

It's still in progress since last 3 hours and at step "**Exporting data from database**". Is there any way where I can check detail status of export simultaneously while export is going on ? 
I need to check like how many rows it has processed till now or how much data exported till now etc?

Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: Pity this doesn't have an answer (Or did you manage to find something?) I am sitting in the same situation now.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this as well, except I'm needing to check the status in Azure via their API.

Comment: Still searching..

Comment: This is sooo frustrating, only I'm trying to copy 330 GB of data.  I could drop that figure to 50 GB if only I could exclude certain columns from the export.  After an hour, every single table still says "In Progress".  It looks to be stuck on the two biggest tables straight out of the gate.
Life would be much easier if I could just import a standard backup file taken from an SQL Managed instance.